# Select first option only in language switcher dropdown module

Tags: 7, navigation

I have integrated language switcher dropdown module, which contains four languages
English, China, Japan, Korea.

No matter user browse from these languages, I just would like to select only English language only in dropdown. How can i acheieve this ? Do i need to implements hook ?

Comment: Not sure if I correctly understand your second paragraph. Maybe because of some minor English errors, which you should try to correct via edit of your question. But because of the "I just would like to select only English language only in dropdown", I wonder why in that case you want to use the language switcher dropdown module? It seems like "you add a select list, but do not want anybody to use an option different from selection = English". Probably I'm missing something, so try to re-edit your question to better explain your question, ok?

Comment: Actually I have a option named as "International Sites" in Dropdown instead of English and as per my client requirement, "International Sites" option is selected, regardless of country.